# Concatenate several tables in R

Tags: r

I have 5 `data.frames` with 10 rows, which correspond to 10 politicians.
I use `table()` to count all the political groups in each `data.frame`.

So I get 10 tables like this :

```
grpol.1 <- table(df1$group_pol)
grpol.1
  NI RRDP  SRC  UDI  UMP 
  1    2   3    3    1 
grpol.2
  RRDP  UDI  ECOLO 
  5       4      1
```

Now, I would like to concatenate (by column) all of these tables into just one `data.frame`. There are 7 political groups in all.
*Note* all these tables do not have the same number of columns.

I would like to obtain something like:

```
 group_pol  grpol.1  grpol.2  ... grpol.5
1 NI              1        0
2 RRDP            2        5
3 SRC             3        0
4 UDI             3        4 
5 UMP             1        0
6 GDR             0        0
7 ECOLO           0        1
```

Normally, in this case, I would use merging. However it seems impossible to convert tables to `data.frame`s in order to merge.
So, what is the alternative to concatenate tables which do not have similar columns ?

Thanks for help,

Comment: There is an `as.data.frame` method for tables. I get the idea this might be simpler taking a different route. Why not offer a fer example data objects to work with?

Comment: if you don't want to use merge, maybe you can use match?

Comment: also if you share an example of the original data.frames there might be a different, more direct approach to begin with.

Comment: What you should be doing is to `rbind` all data.frames with an extra `id` column (unique to each `data.frame`), and then "cast" it (using `dcast` from `reshape2` with `fun.aggregate=length`).

Comment: Whenever you find yourself naming variables like `df1`, `df2`, `df3`, `df4` and `df5` you are in fact making a fake list. R however has no idea that they belong together and can't hardly do anything to help you work with them. Make a real list instead and you can do much more with much less code. I regularly hold computer exercises for molecular biology majors and see all the time, but never let it pass. I don't mean to be anal, but it will save you *lots* of time and agony.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll start by making some example data

```
grpol.1 <- as.table(c(a=1,b=2, d=3, g=4))
grpol.2 <- as.table(c(b=1, c=2, e=3, f=4))
grpol.3 <- as.table(c(b=198, d=281, e=-12, g=612))
```

The primitive way of solving it would be

```
merge(as.data.frame(grpol.1),
      merge(as.data.frame(grpol.2),
            as.data.frame(grpol.3), by="Var1", all=TRUE),
      by="Var1", all=TRUE)
```

Giving you the following output

```
  Var1 Freq Freq.x Freq.y
1    a    1     NA     NA
2    b    2      1    198
3    d    3     NA    281
4    g    4     NA    612
5    c   NA      2     NA
6    e   NA      3    -12
7    f   NA      4     NA
```

However, if you have a lot of tables it is better to keep them in a list so you don't need to write out all their names every time you want to access them.

```
l <- list(grpol.1, grpol.2, grpol.3)
l <- lapply(l, as.data.frame)
f <- function(x, y) merge(x, y, by="Var1", all=TRUE)
Reduce(f, l)
```

This is especially important if you want you code to work with an arbitrary number of tables. The next time you run your code you might have 6 tables instead of 5, who knows?

Comment: It was so simple... sorry. :)
Thanks a lot,

Comment: ... the first solution is perfect. I keep the second one for later, it could be precious in deed.